# sudoers: how to disable requiretty per user

Tags: sudo

I don't want to comment out the line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Instead, I only want a certain user not to require a tty.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You said that you want one particular user to not require a tty. That's the default behavior. Nevertheless, you can explicitly set that like this:

```
Defaults:username !requiretty
```

If you want everyone else to require a tty, then you'll have to uncommment the line.

Comment: Btw., requiretty is active per default on RHEL5. Good to know its not like that in other distributions.

Comment: This one might help someone. http://serverfault.com/questions/72708/execute-su-c-over-ssh

Answer (score 6):

RedHat now recommends removing 'Defaults requiretty', conforming with the [source code defaults](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html).  In [Security Advisory RHSA-2016:2593](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016:2593), Redhat patched /etc/sudoers, removing line 'Defaults requiretty'

For additional details, see:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196451
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1155247&action=diff

Also, per user requiretty exceptions DO NOT WORK for RHEL/CENTOS 7 (sudo 1.8.6p7)

Comment: This is really great info but does not technically answer the question.

Comment: Do you have a link to  a ticket about per user defaults not working on RHEL/CENTOS 7 ?  Or maybe a link to release notes saying this has been fixed post 1.8.6p7 ?

I'm not seeing anything about it under https://www.sudo.ws/stable.html