# Using sudo in WinSCP

Tags: centos, sudo, winscp

I need to update `httpd.conf` in `/usr/local/apache/conf` path.

I have generated SSH key in cpanel, and selected it in Advanced options in SSH/Authentication section.

Also I have tried two different SCP/Shell options in this section (default, `/bin/bash`, `sudo su -`)

And as I file protocol I select SCP.

And I can login but, am getting permission denied message that I can not edit or download file. I have also tried to set 777 for folder and 664 for files, but it is also not letting me to do this change.

I am using Centos 6.5.

Session log :

```
2014-01-06 08:23:13.128 Using SCP protocol.
. 2014-01-06 08:23:13.128 Doing startup conversation with host.
. 2014-01-06 08:23:13.182 Skipping host startup message (if any).
! 2014-01-06 08:23:13.182 stdin: is not a tty
! 2014-01-06 08:23:13.182 sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
. 2014-01-06 08:23:13.182 Server sent command exit status 1
. 2014-01-06 08:23:13.182 Disconnected: All channels closed
* 2014-01-06 08:23:13.241 (EFatal) **Connection has been unexpectedly closed.** Server sent command exit status 1.
* 2014-01-06 08:23:13.241 Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).
```

Comment: Try this. Its worked for me. https://easycodeforall.com/winscp-root-access-login.html

Answer (score 4):

I want to share my solution because I'm also searching several time for a workaround. I'm using CentOS7 right now and try to get connetion via WinSCP (Pubkey Auth).

sshd_config

```
..
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
..
```

@CentOS
visudo - add following 2 entrys

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su
Defaults:username !requiretty
```

WinSCP settings:

```
Disable keyboard-interactive @ SSH authentication settings solves the problem for me. 
SCP settings command: sudo su -
```

Answer (score 3):

As @pragnesh has suggested, you will find all the instructions in WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo)

Not only you need to add the `sudo -s` shell and `yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` line (or similar) to the `sudoers`, but you also need to make sure the `sudo` does not require TTY.

While this is the default behavior, you may have it configured differently. Make sure you remove the `requiretty` option from the `sudoers` file.

You can also change this only per user, see [sudoers: how to disable requiretty per user](https://serverfault.com/q/111064/168875).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sudo on login setting with WinSCP

Check this [WinSCP FAQ](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo).

Comment: Hi, thank you on response, I have take a look at a link, add a sudoers file(644 permission on a file), and content, after that I have select sudo -s as a Schell option, and I couldn't even login, I get this message now : "Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended)." And with bash option, I have permission problems.

Comment: what configuration did you added on /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: my_username ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL This.

Comment: try doing as per this post http://holisticsecurity.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/open-files-ubuntu-root-from-winscp-remotely/

Comment: @pragnesh, thank you, I tried that, now I get this error : Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running a SFTP server? I have google it out, end up here http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2918, tried everything, and still nothing. :(