# Check_nrpe unable to read output from script

Tags: linux, redhat, nagios, nrpe

Script is at Server:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ ! $# == 1 ]; then
echo "Usage check_cluster "
fi;
clu_srv=$1
error="stopped"
error1="disabled"
error2="recoverable"
host1=`sudo /usr/sbin/clustat|grep $1| awk {'print $2'}`
host2=`sudo /usr/sbin/clustat|grep $1| awk {'print $3'}`
service1=`sudo /usr/sbin/clustat|grep $clu_srv| awk {'print $1'}`
if [[ "$host2" == "$error" ]] || [[ "$host2" == "$error1" ]]; then
echo "CRITICAL - Cluster $clu_srv service failover on $host1 and state is '$host2'"
else
echo "OK - Cluster  $clu_srv service is on $host1 and state is '$host2'"
fi;

##--EndScript
```

It receives thee argument from script correctly.  When I running this script manually at 
Server from command line it returns correct information, for example:

```
# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_rhcs-ERS NFSService
OK - Cluster  NFSService service is on NODE1 and state is 'started'
```

But when I tried with  the script (check_nrpe) remotely with following command its showing 
incorrect information:

```
# ./check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_rhcs-ERS
OK - Cluster  NFSService service is on  and state is ''
```

nrpe.cfg:

```
# command[check_rhcs-ERS]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_rhcs-ERS  NFSService
```

What is Wrong with the script, How to fix it?

Comment: Modify the script to log its output so you can see what it's doing.  For example:  Add `-x` to the first line (`#!/bin/bash -x`) and immediately after that add a new line after that to capture the stderr+stdout output to a logfile (`exec > /tmp/nrpetest.$$.log 2>&1`) then call the script via NRPE again.  Review the log file that is generated to see where the script is failing.

Comment: Additionally, nrpe checks rely on the return code (or "exit code") of the script/command to determine whether the check returned OK, WARNING, or CRITICAL status.  Your last `if` statement should include appropriate `exit` commands to return the desired return code.  https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured sudo correctly its probably a problem with `Requiretty`, you should tell sudo not to require for nrpe.

See [sudoers: how to disable requiretty per user](https://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user)

Answer (score 1):

Your NRPE user most likely doesn't have permissions to run commands with `sudo` access.

To allow this, you can add the line below to your `/etc/sudoers` file using `visudo`. You can also omit the `NFSService` part if you don't want to restrict that part.

```
nrpe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/clustat NFSService
```

That said, your script does need improving. It also only takes *one* parameter, not three - the `$2` and `$3` variables are `awk` arguments, not `bash` parameters.

My partially-edited version is below:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage check_cluster " >&2
  exit 1
fi

clu_srv=$1

error="stopped"
error1="disabled"
error2="recoverable"

host1=$(sudo /usr/sbin/clustat | grep "${clu_srv}" | awk '{ print $2 }')
host2=$(sudo /usr/sbin/clustat | grep "${clu_srv}" | awk '{ print $3 }')
service1=$(sudo /usr/sbin/clustat | grep "${clu_srv}" | awk '{ print $1}')
```

The error-handling part of your script needs clarifying - what conditions do you want to catch? Your `OK` output gives the status for `host2`, but says that the service is on `host1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help..Already Given the  permission to nrpe user. May be something wrong with the script.

Comment: If it works using your user, there is nothing wrong with the script. You can elevate yourself to the `nrpe` user's shell by running `su nrpe` as root - if you get bumped back to your root shell, you can change the user's shell in `/etc/passwd` - just remember to change it back when you're done debugging.

Comment: I already debugged before using root user, its showing same result.I thing there is no issue for permissions.

Comment: You said that you "running this script manually at Server from command line it returns correct information". Can you please clarify?

Comment: Using nrpe user I can run the script manually at server from cmd line...Actually I gives all right to nrpe user but still same result occured.