# getting NRPE: Unable to read output when running from server

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I am getting NRPE: Unable to read output when trying to connect to the docker container using nagios.
When I run this script directly on the client machine it is successfully returning me the number of rows in mongo db. But when I run it remotely from the server I am getting unable to read output.

```
executing from nagios server
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H hostipaddress -c check_mongocount
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

*check_mongocount* script is basically conneccting to the docker container and counting the number of rows for a particular customer for a date.

```
count=`sudo /bin/docker exec -it container mongo dbname --quiet -u "test" -p "test" --authenticationDatabase "test" --eval '(db.test.count( { $and: [{create_at: {$gte: NumberLong("1499227200"), $lt: NumberLong("1499313599")}},{customerid:1}]}))'
```

*/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg* has the following line added.

```
command[check_mongocount]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/test.sh
```

I have `nrpe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` in my */etc/sudoers* file. Though nrpe has all rights to execute the docker command it is failing to return the count value.

Comment: I guess your problem is answered here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/797049/check-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-from-script/797081#797081